# Go - how to organize code for dynamic packages

Tags: go

I have a small web application written in Go.  It is created a base for a larger system and I would like it to be extendable where components can be added/removed without needing this base to be modified in any way.

The structure is currently:

```
       App
         Modules
             Core
                 ... Core Files Here ...
       app.go
   main.go
```

app.go will contain a routing method which should take a web request and based on the request path know which module is responsible for handling the request.  Each module/component having its on controller.

Each component will have its own package name so i think this is going to be impossible since go forces an explicit import.

For example i may add a new module/component called say blog such as:

```
       App
         Modules
             Core
                 ... Core Files Here ...
                 controller.go
             Blog
                 ... Blog Files Here ...
                 controller.go
       app.go
   main.go
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. Since Go does not support dynamically loaded libraries at the moment, you need to probably recompile your application whenever you add/remove any components. The simplest way therefore would be a `yourapp/core` package with the following:

- an `Application` type with an `ServeHTTP` method that acts as your main application
- a `Component` interface that all your components have to implement. Your might want include a `BaseUrl() string` and a `ServeHTTP` method there.
- a `Register` method to your `Application` type, that can be used to add new components to your app.

Your components can then be implemented in separate packages (e.g. `yourapp/blog`) and they will probably depend on your `yourapp/core` package.

The only thing that still needs to be "user-editable" is the `main.go` file, which might look like this:

```
func main() {
    app := core.NewApplication()
    app.Register(blog.Blog{
        Title: "My Personal Blog",
    })
    app.Register(...)
    app.Run()
}
```

Another approach might be to define an RPC interface for your components (which might include functions like `RegisterComponent`, `UnregisterComponent` and a `GetGlobalConfig`).

Then, you can run those components in separate processes which has the advantage that you can start/stop/reload those components dynamically and they can not break your main app. Take a look at the [net/rpc](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/) package and maybe even [httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#NewSingleHostReverseProxy) if you want to use this approach instead.

Comment: Upvoted. A variant might be that each component does `core.Register(...)` in an init() function.